# Loading ResourceDictionary resource at runtime from assemblies with the same name

Tags: wpf, runtime, uri, resourcedictionary

I encountered some problem when trying to load resources from two separate assemblies having **the same name** but **located in a different folder**:

- C:\folder1\fcl.dll
- C:\folder2\fcl.dll

A `ResourceDictionary` named **Resources.xaml** is embedded (as a Page) in each of these assemblies.

To load the first `ResourceDictionary`, I use the following snippet :

```
// Load the assembly in memory
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\folder1\FCL.Dll");

// Get Dictionnary 
var uri = string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};Component/Resources.xaml", assembly.GetName().Name);
var resourceDictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(uri) };
```

This is running !

But when I try to load the second `ResourceDictionary` with the same snippet of code (just changing `Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\folder1\FCL.Dll")` by `Assembly.LoadFrom(@"c:\folder2\FCL.Dll")`, **it does not load resources from c:\folder2\fcl.dll, but those stored in the previously loaded c:\folder1\fcl.dll :-(**

The cause: The **shortAssemblyName** field of the URI is the same, in may case FCL:

```
 var uri = string.Format("pack://application:,,,/{0};Component/Resources.xaml", assembly.GetName().Name)
```

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two assemblies loaded with the same name, so I think the second Assembly.LoadFrom is just being ignored.   You are probably going to have to rename one of the assemblies.

Comment: Correction: you can have multiple assemblies loaded with the same name if you are using strong names and if the versions differ.  You would then need to specify the version as part of the URI.